# Atualizar pacotes do SO de um container de Banco de Dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, docker

Estou refazendo um servidor do Zabbix aqui na empresa, onde vou atualizar da versão 3.2 para 4.0

Estou pensando em usar docker para facilitar a vida, já que no DockerHub tem imagens para o Zabbix-Server, para o Zabbix-Web, e pretendo usar a imagem oficial do MySQL5.7 como database server.

Mas ai entra a dúvida

Quando eu for atualizar os pacotes do SO e do Database no container do MySQL, não é simples mover todos os dados do database, que chega facilmente a 50Gb para outro container.

Qual seria a solução mais adequada?

Comment: Achei sua pergunta super interessante, pelo que estive conversando com o um consultor a ideia é você mapear um volume do seu banco de dados e ter somente o serviço do mysql rodando no container.

Comment: A ideia do container é exatamene ser efêmero, como já foi citado, o ideal é você persistir seus dados em volumes. Daí pode escrever um dockerfile pro seu cenário (ou montar um um docker-compose) e só subir, pra atualizar também vai ser tranquilo.

Comment: Recomendo montar um lab com o seu cenário, usar as imagens oficiais como base e escrever um docker-compose, persistindo seus dados em volumes, daí vai ver se atende seu caso ;)

Comment: Na [documentação do zabixx](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/installation/containers) inclusive já tem um how to bem detalhado, e no [repositório do github](https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix-docker) tem alguns exemplos de docker-compose

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que trabalhar com volumes para salvar os dados fora do contêiner, quando for atualizar só altera a imagem do contêiner, mas os dados são os mesmos

Answer (score 0):

Exato volumes são a melhor forma de trabalhar com informação sensível, mas se atente que se os componentes do Zabbix forem executados dentro de um cluster você precisa de volumes em rede (NFS) pois os containers podem não ser inicializados no host que tem os volumes, caso seja uma simples máquina com docker seja feliz com os volumes.

Esse link explica bem como fazer e com volumes:

http://blog.aeciopires.com/zabbix-docker/